# Sikuli Integration with TeamCity?

Tags: java, automation, sikuli, sikuli-script

I have integrated Sikuli with TeamCity, but I have strange error.

```
[error] Location: outside any screen (398055760, 0) - subsequent actions might not work as expected.
```

My report shows me black screenshot!

Have you ever encountered this issue ?

Comment: https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/295525

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to remove TC agent because it is running as windows service.
What should we do ? You have to install new TC agent with to support UI tests, all you do is to deselect Windows Service option while installing the agent.

Why we get this? Sikuli as we know depends on real UI and it's looking for the images in that UI but when we install the agent as windows service a new session will open behind the scenes (headless), so if you take a screenshots while running the automation you will get black screens.

see this: http://jake.ginnivan.net/teamcity-ui-test-agent

Comment: I have a similar problem, but if I remove the TC agent, will it not break all the other stuff that runs successfully on TeamCity?

Comment: If you closed the service you can start it as well.

Answer (score 1):

Since we are talking image processing as the core of this engine.
I recommend writing the scripts directly on the machine that has the build agent installed.
It sounds like you have discrepancies between your "dev" pc and the agent one. (Maybe you are using two screens on the dev machine while the Agent one has only one?)
Also , YOU Have to have a physical GPU on the build agent machine AND THE AGENT HAS TO RUN AS A USER ON STARTUP! (For this, i've created a batch file that launches the agent at startup)

So you'll disable/Uninstall TC agent SERVICE

Add a batch file that looks like "C:\BuildAgent\bin\agent.bat start RunAs /profile /user:DevUser\administrator CMD"  To the startup folder.

Now when the Machine launches you will see that the TC build Agent runs under a user account and MAY interact with your desktop